# Mismatched tag in code and APPT2 error

Tags: android-linearlayout, mismatch

I have this code where I always get an error about a mismatched tag, I cant see the error myself, can someone help me? thanks a million.

And I also get this error: Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailsSongs">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_widht="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="FFECB3"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/songdetailsdescription" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientaion="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Linearlayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layouth_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layouth_height="match_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder_dark_large"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/songdetailscontentdescriptionalbumart"
                        android:scaleType="center" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="16dp"
                            android:text="@string/songnameplaceholder"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/songauthorplaceholder"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/media_controls_play_dark_small"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                            android:paddingBtottom="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/songdetailsplaynow" />
```

> This is where is says that there is an error (LinearLayout) below this comment

```
                    </Linearlayout>


                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/songdetailssimilarsongs"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/related_albums"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" >
                    <include layout="@layout/relatedsongslist" />
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/songdescriptionplaceholder" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <include layout="@layout/player" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If there is "an error about a mismatched tag", can you share the exact error message? At first view, I see `LinearLayout` and `Linearlayout`, shouldn't that occur in only one type?

Comment: Error:(100) error: mismatched tag. and Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Answer (score 0):

almost all your tags are mismatched and its causing the problem, i dont know what you trying but i think your best bet will be to try and restart the design again

but this is what i could help. rewrote your xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DetailsSongs">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_widht="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="FFECB3"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/songdetailsdescription" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientaion="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Linearlayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layouth_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layouth_height="match_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder_dark_large"
            android:contentDescription="@string/songdetailscontentdescriptionalbumart"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/songnameplaceholder"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/songauthorplaceholder"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/media_controls_play_dark_small"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingBtottom="2dp"
                android:text="@string/songdetailsplaynow" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </Linearlayout>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/songdetailssimilarsongs"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/related_albums"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" >
            <include layout="@layout/relatedsongslist" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/songdescriptionplaceholder" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <include layout="@layout/player" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Try this out and hopefully could help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! :-) Unfortunately it still says "mismatched tag".